# Should I handle 404 when it can't happen

Tags: android, node.js, error-handling

I'm trying to make this as specific as possible...

I have an android app that calls a node.js back end for login and other purposes, I'm writing both the apps.

I'm making a login call to the node.js api, amongst other calls to get data etc. Should I code to handle 404 and 401 errors etc. or should I just expect that the responses will be ok?

Comment: I think you do not need handle 404 , but you should handle 401 and other expect error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you won't know what will happen in the future.  In particular a 401 is likely if authentication expires (you do expire your auth tokens, right?).  Now that doesn't mean each of those needs unique error handling codes.  Generally you can lump most errors into the same screen.  Typically I'd say you see auth failures (by bouncing you to a login screen), general errors, and maybe timeout/network failures, but it varies by app.

Comment: Yep to expiring tokens. And yes, non auth will bounce to login screen. So that's fine. Do you generally handle all of these errors for api calls in a utils class or such like?